# Open an Application in "Standards Document Mode" in IE-9 on saba cloud

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, backbone.js, scorm

I have an e-Learning application on saba cloud. It is working fine on all browsers except IE-9.
Some functionality in this application is not working on IE-9 only(It is working fine on IE-8,IE-10).

The Interesting part is that, this application is not working properly in (IE-9+ Saba) only.
It is working fine in scorm cloud in In IE-9.It is working fine when i put my application on my local server and accessed in IE-9.

Later on I found out it is because Documents mode of Saba in IE-9 is "quirks". I changed document mode to "standards" using Developer Tool (F12) and application started working properly.

I have tried following ways

1. Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`
2. Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

The meta tag technique is working for Scorm Cloud but not for Saba Cloud.

Is there any way to set Document mode to Standards in IE-9 without using Developer Tool(F12) or Meta Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Saba's course rendering policy for IE-9.

Our course was hosted on saba and it was part of iframe of saba's page.

By default saba opens all courses in "quirks" mode in IE-9.

Thus all the tags and strategies for forcing our course to run in “Standards Document Mode” was overridden by saba's course container page.

Answer (score 0):

Have the you the HTML5 document type directive on top of your page `<!DOCTYPE html>`

[Microsoft doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I have used <!DOCTYPE html> But It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a typo but maybe worth pointing out anyway - the code in your first example should read:

```
content="IE=edge"
```

not:

```
content="IE=egde"
```

Comment: Sorry For Typo

but in application there is no such typo mistake.